# Changing whisker length in `geom_boxplot()` and plotly

Tags: r-plotly

How do I change the length of the whiskers when working with a `geom_boxplot()` that I would like to be rendered as a plotly object?

I tried to change the `coef` argument in the `geom_boxplot()` function from 1.5 to something wider but that did not work.